# Typescript: function return type is different when a parameter is undefined or its type is asserted

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

### The need

The code is simple but my use case is complex:

```js
type MyFn = <B extends ['A']>(
  param?: B
) => B extends undefined ? 'TYPE_1' : 'TYPE_2'

// so that
const test1 = myFn() // shall be type TYPE_1
const test2 = myFn(['A']) // shall be type TYPE_2
```

- I would like that if `param` is undefined, then the type is `'TYPE_1'` else it is `'TYPE_2'`
- `param`shall be dynamically typed, the goal is that the IDE autocompletes/validates values when writing the values inside the array
- the type of `param` inside the function shall be at least (string[] | undefined)

### What I have tried

I tried a lot of different configurations without success: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=27&pln=24&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAYgOxgXhgHgEIygDxCmQBMBnGAbQHIBBagXQD4AKYGGCAQwCcuBbAPwAuGNmABKdEzF5CxcjACupKADMAlsigkYgmNQAqATQAKAUQD6ARmoxRRs1YBM1YMABuvGF1EIU6DAs3HxCUmgywbwCegYmFjZ2DvEu1FJcFFzIYO4AxgD2yGQgMETF1oFcLFIA9DUwZAAWXAA2LTAARrDg0DApNsAFRSVlIM6VLDT0DLX1Ta3tXaWQsP3O7sB1MAByAPKGMADquwBKANIAktsA4jCgK-BIyOMYOHJEpBRTjDAAPsqqTTaEisdicaJCUTicIyXAED6KFQkdRaHSxRwJWz2OJOSyudxeHg%20Zx%20J4vIIhASCGEUiHo-pY5K41zpTLZPKFYqlKDlPGVZzVO5DLmjZx8-mTOiMCQbLZ7A7Hc5XW73Xr%20ZAAZkCmDBhgANGC4fJPlQpQw-gDkUCdMBQRxKZC%20hbodInfCFBRijwtABzSjm-QYqyMnEJfGebxcDWklBajBRULU10JmKBhlJUOpVk%20dmDTkjHkgayWOM%20DWCvPDbnFMVayrl74zIA)

The closest I could get actually was with this code:

```js
type MyFn = <
  T,
  B extends ['A']
>(
  param?: T | B
) => T extends string[] ? 'TYPE_2' : 'TYPE_1'

var a: MyFn3 = (param?) => (param ? 'TYPE_1' : 'TYPE_2') as any

const test1 = a() // IS type TYPE_1
const test2  = a(['A']) // IS be type TYPE_2
```

But **the problem** is that the inferred type inside of the function is `any` because `T` has no constraint type. But at the moment we constraint the `T` type, the condition in the return type returns always true.

**Is there any solutions to get around that problem ?**

---

### Real world use case

The main goal behind such a type is to define an array of string as props address of an object, and return the value at that address.
Eg: `['level1', 'level2']` would return `myObject.level1.level2`

[Here is a simplified version of this real world use case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmOB7AJlANjAvDA3sGQmAQwC4YBnEAJwEsA7AcwBoCiAjc3GFLmKPgDM%20jcuyRJ0UYvRgBfeYrnBlwQQFd6AYxC0ksgLZgAYvQA8bQgEFq1fgA8QUeigowA2lYC6MAD4erZhgAIR9-TyDgoIBhMIDImKCAES9WIhgrBycXNwAKKjomGAAyGABrKDAkQXhEVAwASjSiYKznVxh8mgZGEvLK6trkNHRPLybLGGi2nM6Cnr6KqpqEYYwx91CJ9KSZjq7C3tKlwdX60e9Nr3dYhuAAPlzJiGIQAAsAfnIbO1L3Yi%20GSC7EBURgWkB0SCKEBKWahC0%20kEtEYgO43UYjCg1AAorYkNQAJKCABySBAAGUoCBAeJJNJZMoGuQAArUJAGWgUKBmFmvN4AJWp6mo9AAKpAeT8gmcRkFAiFEjAkvd7nhJtRhaK8ApiG4ZGAVMBjcaoPYIASQDBwNAYHz3kKQCLxZKLOlpZNHc6JbazdkOkLEdQUGZ5kwggb7vCMns3GGWCFY5RuuGpkn48l0ynGA9sDBJj8k5o0Mj6FAUDAPjAvaKfbBSAXbEmxpXq1qXdAWw33U2-e03BEQj4qzWO1ANqEYN2iIW%207NB2DYq3R3WJ9cl9PrL3HP34oqpslh22nbXJWubtcUlPJoQV5KTcBEfQqDBNSf6AB5dgAKwAMlAADcMAAdVod4kHUEA%20WoYgDDzIxTFyBoYAAehQmASQ-MUYAAdwJMoeiCAx1HQXQICka1JTcBgqGkCtTjqEZH30F832dL8-0AjAAEZ4JMehcncABydghPGVD0Lw6gCKYZjnytNjRQ4-8gPQAAmPjEOE0SgiElAxOQtDcPwno5NY9tlK49AAGZNIE7ShN0-TdKgAyJOM6TTKfcz30s1S8TsHAEPskTHJgIT6DCoTXPEozsXZOwuRgHEAA0WRxaIxRxXYKAYLRYDAmAAOIdBaBQV4oDjbN9U1fhBEEKAdFoVSwH6ZYhnOc9YiAA)

Comment: Why not just use a default for the type parameter? https://tsplay.dev/mxaABW

Comment: Didn't know that we could do that  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `B` type is never `undefined`, because `['A']` is never undefined. The compiler can effectively simplify your expression:

```
type MyFn = <B extends ['A']>(
  param?: B
) => B extends undefined ? 'TYPE_1' : 'TYPE_2'
```

to

```
type MyFn = <B extends ['A']>(
  param?: B
) => false ? 'TYPE_1' : 'TYPE_2'
```

to

```
type MyFn = <B extends ['A']>(
  param?: B
) => 'TYPE_2'
```

The fact that `param` is optionally `B` has no effect on `B` itself.

You need to broaden `B`:

```
type MyFn = <B extends ['A'] | undefined>(
```

which produces the correct result for

```
const test1 = myFn(undefined) // TYPE_1
```

and then default to make it work when omitted:

```
type MyFn = <B extends ['A'] | undefined = undefined>(
```

which produces the correct result for

```
const test1 = myFn() // TYPE_1
```